# Pagination for custom posts loop

Tags: shortcode, pagination

I have made little shortcodes to insert data to my home screen. I loop over total number of posts and output pre-styled html.

My question is, is it possible to also make pagination for that kind of loops? For example if I have 10 posts and I would like to display 5 and then under these are link to another 5. Or if this isn't possible, what direction I should look?

Currently I'm displaying data like that (this is only for title as I groomed it to be shorter for putting it here):

```
    add_shortcode('title-snippet', 'wpc_shortcode_title');
    function wpc_shortcode_title() {
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1000' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

        $html = '<div></div>';

        for($x = 0; $x < count($recent_posts); $x++) {
            $html .= '
                <div class="vce-text-block">
                    <div class="vce-text-block-wrapper vce">
                        <p>
                            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Playfair Display;">
                                <span style="font-size: 21.3333px;">
                                    '.$recent_posts[$x]["post_title"].'
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }

        return <<<HTML
            $html
        HTML;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post loop with pagination in the shortcode **[title-snippet type="post" limit="5"]**:

```
function wpc_shortcode_title( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, 'type' => 'post'), $atts ) );

$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

query_posts(  array ( 
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'post_type' => $type, 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' =>'menu_order', 
    'paged' => $paged ) );

$list = ' ';   

while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

    $list .= '<article class="listing-view clearfix">' 
    . '<div class="listing-content">' 
    . '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>' 
    .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'
    . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
    . '</div>'
    . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'listing-thumb')  . '<span></span></a>'
    . '</article>';
}

return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. $list 
. '<div class="nav-previous">' . get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) . '</div>'
. '<div class="nav-next">' . get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) . '</div>'
. '</div>' .
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'title-snippet', 'wpc_shortcode_title' );
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work really well. I assume it's possible to configure it to show numbers 1 2 instead of "Older posts"/"Newer posts"?
But anyway, you're true lifesaver, have been messing with it days already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to show number pagination. Try below-updated code:

```
function wpc_shortcode_title( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, 'type' => 'post'), $atts ) );

$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

query_posts(  array ( 
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'post_type' => $type, 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' =>'menu_order', 
    'paged' => $paged ) );

$list = ' ';   

while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

    $list .= '<article class="listing-view clearfix">' 
    . '<div class="listing-content">' 
    . '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>' 
    .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'
    . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
    . '</div>'
    . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'listing-thumb')  . '<span></span></a>'
    . '</article>';
}

    global $wp_query;
    $args_pagination = array(
            'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $paged
            );
    $list .= '<div class="post-nav">';
        $list .= paginate_links( $args_pagination);
    $list .= '</div>';

return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. $list 
. '</div>' .
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'title-snippet', 'wpc_shortcode_title' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Solved a lot of issues!